# How to load dotspacemacs/user-config from a different file?

Tags: spacemacs, configuration-files

My default spacemacs dotfile defines `dotspacemacs/user-config`, and I suppose my user config is supposed to go inside this function. However the file itself is quite large and I'd like to isolate my own settings in a separate file.

I've put my dotfile in `~/.spacemacs/init.el`. I'd like the user config to be loaded from `~/.spacemacs/user-config.el`. How can I do this?

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration for user code:
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs startup, after layer
configuration.
Put your configuration code here, except for variables that should be set
before packages are loaded."

 ;; load stuff from user-config.el here

)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(load 'user-config)`

Notice that you can and should put the whole `dotspacemacs/user-config` function in that file. This avoids reloading any files if the function is called more than once.

Type `C-h f` to get help about a function by typing its name.